# c++ How can I do the casting float->uchar in OpenCV?

Tags: c++, opencv, casting

I have a problem with my gaussian mask 1D.
I have the function:

```
f(x) = exp(-0.5*x^^2 / sigma^^2)
```

So, I made this code in OpenCV:

```
 Mat getMask(int sigma){
     Mat out(1,6*sigma+1,CV_8UC1);  
     for (int i=0; i<6*sigma+1; i++){
        float f =  exp((-1)*(i-(6*sigma)/2)/(sigma*sigma));

        out.at<uchar>(Point(i,0)) = static_cast<unsigned char>(f);
      }
      return out;
}
```

But, when I apply the mask on my image, it returns a black one.
I tried to control what it is on my Mat out in every moment with a cout, and I get characters like a smily face and so on. What can I do?
This is what I see with cout inside for loop:

```
Float: 20.0855
Casting float to unsigned char: ¶
What I insert: ¶
```

Comment: How did you `cout` it?

Comment: why are you using a uchar Mat for this, not a float one ? (horrible rounding errors)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display the value of a pixel at output stream , you should do explicit cast as shown below -

```
cout << (int) image.at<uchar>(i,j) << endl;
```